# which of the following subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ are uncountable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

1. $\{\,(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2\mid a\leq b\,\}$
2. $\{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2\mid a+b\in\mathbb Q\,\}$
3. $\{\,(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2\mid ab\in \mathbb Z\,\}$
4. $\{\,(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2\mid a,b\in \mathbb Q\,\}$.

I know option 1 is uncountable and option 4 is countable. 
I think option 2, 3 are uncountable but I am not sure. Can someone help me?

Comment: For 3: Fix $a= 1/ \sqrt{2}$ and find an uncountable set that $b$ sits.

Comment: Is . in 3) supposed to be multiplication?

Comment: @karolis YES IT IS MULTIPICATION

Answer (score 5):

For 2) note that $(x,-x)$ is in the set with $x\in\mathbb R$ arbitrary.
For 3) note that $(x,0)$ is in the set with $x\in\mathbb R$ arbitrary.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Q}$ being countable,$\mathbb{Q^2}$ is also countable and consequently $4$ is countable.Choosing a=y,b=n/y where n is a natural number and y is a positive irrational and less than 1 we can satisfy the requirement of $3$ in uncountably many ways, irrationals in ($0,1$) being uncountable.
$a=x-y,b=x+y \text{ (where x is rational and y irrational) }\Rightarrow a+b=2x\in \mathbb{Q}$ i.e there are uncountably many choices for 2. Choosing a and b both irrationals we can satisfy the requirement of 1 in uncountably many ways.So $1,2,3$ are uncountable.